# Is there a way to access the fields of a record, selected by a radio button widget in Google App Maker?

Tags: radio-button, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, google-app-maker

## Summary

I am fairly new to AppMaker and this question centres on hierarchies. I have a Taxonomy table with a straight forward parent has children hierarchical relationship.

TaxonomyGroup -> has many Features -> has many Values

I've been working on a way to traverse this hierarchy using **tile/grid widget**.

When I reach the last node of the tree-structure I display this as a set of radio-buttons, representing the permitted options.

#### Example

Starting group is: *Car*

a Car has the following *features:*

-*Colour*
    -Red
    -Blue
    -Silver
    -Green

-*Transmission*
    -Automatic
    -Manual

-*Fuel*
    -Petrol
    -Hybrid
    -Electric

If the parent group was Motorcycle, I would have a different set of features and options (permitted values).

A user selects the following for a Car:

+Colour
    -Silver

+Trans 
    -Automatic

+Fuel 
    -Electric

### Issue

While I can capture Silver, Automatic, Electric as the options selected, I cannot pick up the ID or any other fields of the record represented by the radio button selected.

#### Grid widget set-up

> Taxonomy Grid Panel.....   parent layer DS = Taxonomy (table) Id In [list]
>
> Taxonomy Grid Child panel 'child' layer DS = TaxonomyChildren, ParentId = :parent
>
> > > Radio button list DS = TaxonomyChildren: SubGroups (relation)

NB the radio button list sits within the Taxonomy Grid Child panel, so the list of options changes, based on the feature.

#### Radio button code onValueEdit event

```
// provides the row index of the selected Feature. e.g 'Transmission'

var rowIndex = widget.root.descendants.TaxonomyChildGridPanel.selectedIndex;

if (rowIndex === 0 ){   
 widget.root.descendants.Feature1.ID = widget.datasource.item.Id;
} else if rowIndex ===1 { 
 widget.root.descendants.Feature2.ID = widget.datasource.item.Id;
  }
: //etc etc   
}
```

#### Radio button widget issue

> > *widget.datasource.item.Id*
> >
> > > returns only the ID for the 1st item in the radio button list.

E.g. record ID 117 representing the option 'Petrol' not Electric as the radio button option selected.

I need to be able to capture the record behind the radio button selection, representing the node (called values) of the tree structure. In particular the ID of the record. Then store it against the creation of a new record, in this example a new Car record.

At present: onValueEdit event: the wrong record_ID is provided and it is always the 1st option in the radio-button list, irrespective of which option was chosen.

**Screen shots**

[Grid panels for hierarchy levels 1 & 2, Radio buttons represent values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPSBQ.png)

[Hierarchy view with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbaJr.png)

Comment: I think I understand your question but its confusing to me. Perhaps you should consider adding some visual aid. A couple of screen shots should help us understand better.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Added pictures to illustrate the intention to browse the hierarchy and collect the values entered. The form for collecting the values is dynamic because the features vary depending on the parent group.

Answer (score 0):

For this question resolution, see the answer given to the following question:

[[How to obtain the record ID of the selected item in a dropdown list in google app-maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062051/how-to-obtain-the-record-id-of-the-selected-item-in-a-dropdown-list-in-google-ap])

Namely: onValueEdit event for the radio button selection the *record id* can be obtained using *newValue*. For Tick Boxes, it is *newValues* which builds an array of answers based on the items ticked.

```
if (!newValue) {
   return;
} else {
   answersDS.query.parameters.answerListIDs.push(newValue);
   answersDS.load();
}
```