# How to obtain the record ID of the selected item in a dropdown list in google app-maker

Tags: dropdown, google-app-maker, dynamic-forms

## Summary

Obtaining the record ID of the selected item in a drop-down list or radio-button UI appears to be a common question, but I have not found the answer for Google AppMaker despite months of searching.

The example use case: is I wish to edit a product that belongs to a family:

Product - (N:1) --> Family

Product - (M:N) --> FeatureValues

#### Example

The product belongs to the family *Credit Card*.

The credit-card family has the following features: |Contactles
|Near field
|Rates
|Chip & Pin|

In the edit form if I change the family the product belongs to then the list of features will change and new values for the features will need to be entered. (*Dynamic form*)

#### Hierarchy table

The family, features and permitted values are held in a single hierarchy table:

Family
|
Features
|
Values

> newValue._key appears to only work for text-box UI items.
>
> Dropdown list:
>
> widget.datasource.item.Id or _key 
>   provides the Product ID of the parent data source, ProductById (because I am editing a single product)
>
> widget.datasource.selectKey(newValue._key); returns undefined

#### Sample code

Drop-down-list
*OnValueChange event:*

> //update the features drop-down based on the taxonomy family selected
>   app.datasources.TaxonomyChildren.query.parameters.parent_fk = app.datasources.TaxonomyFamilies.item.Id;
>
> app.datasources.TaxonomyChildren.load();

If I can pick up the record ID for the selected family in the dropdown list I can set a query.filter.parameter to show the features and values for the newly selected family.

Note: if it is a case you cannot create 'dynamic' forms in Google app-maker, then I'll stop as this has exhausted a lot of time.

[image: Edit product page showing features of family]

Comment: What is your dropdown options binding, is it `@datasources.TaxonomyFamilies.items` or is it `@datasources.TaxonomyFamilies.items..SomeField`? Something else to point out maybe, your dropdown event should be in the onValueEdit event, not the onValueChange event. Also keep in mind that your dropdown datasource inherits the datasource from your form where as your options datasource can be different, so `widget.datasource.item.Id` in a dropdown event would not point to the id of the option selected, however `newValue.Id' will.

Comment: Hi Markus, thank you for your assistance. For the *dropdown* Options '@datasources.TaxonomyFamilies.items..Taxonomy *where taxonomy is a field*    Value: '@datasources.ProductById.item.TaxonomyFamily  *updates the family the product belongs to*. This is a fk in the product table to the hierarchy table representing the single-family  I changed the event to *onEdit* with no improvement. Yes the drop-down options datasource is different.  When I try 'newValue.Id and write this to the console log() it shows *undefined* on the *onEdit event*

Comment: **PS** The 'TaxonomyFamilies' is a calculated query which pulls from the hierarchy table the group that has as its children the *features*. So I am basically trying to obtain the ID for the *option* selected.

Comment: So does your calculated datasource for TaxonomyFamilies have a field that stores your Id from the query that you run against the hierarchy table? I'm asking because a calculated datasource by itself does not have an Id field built in since it is only a temporary representation of records.

Comment: I understand, the query is quite straight forward, and yes the ID of the 'family group' record is included. Taxonomy equals the name of the *family* group, feature or feature-value. See query ->  `Select Distinct h.Id, h.Taxonomy, h.Type, h.Tag
from Hierarchy as h
inner join Hierarchy as h2 on h.Id = h2.Parent_fk
where h.IsDeleted = false and h2.Type = 'Feature' and h2.IsDeleted = false
Order by h.Tag;`

Comment: Ok, I think what you need to change then is your dropdown options. You said the options is `@datasources.TaxonomyFamilies.items..Taxonomy`, so lets say you do `console.log(newValue)` for your dropdown onValueEdit event it would log the 'Taxonomy' field for the item you selected from the dropdown. If you changed your options to `@datasources.TaxonomyFamilies.items..Id` and your names setting to `@datasources.TaxonomyFamilies.items..Taxonomy` then 'newValue' would yield the Id but the dropdown would still just display the Taxonomy field as your selection. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Many thanks Markus. Apologies for the delay I was testing some scenarios to appreciate how it works. *newValue* worked, I've extended the logic to include tick boxes too, using *newValues*. Need to pick-up *un-ticking* tick-box and remove answer. 

Unfortunately, the drop-down *family list* does not update the *taxonomy family* for the product I am editing. Details below...
`Value: @datasource.item.TaxonomyFamily.Id
Options: @datasources.TaxonomyFamilies.items..Id
Names: @datasources.TaxonomyFamilies.items..Taxonomy
The drop-down list inherited datasource is:  *Inherited:ProductById*`

Comment: P.S.
*TaxonomfFamily* is the name of the *relation* from the product side to the hierarchy table and is the _fk in the product table.

I wonder if this is why it is not working and I need to refer to the relationship instead???

Comment: Well if you are using this drop down to set a relation in a form then using a calculated datasource for your options is not really the way to go because you cannot set a relation to a calculated datasource. Unless you are using some other mechanism in your drop down to pull the sql datasource record from the calculated record. I think to further help you I might need additional info on your setup.

Comment: Ok, so switching to a new datasource *TaxonomyFamily*, which isn't' a calculated query, didn't update the product record either. Generates an SQL error as it appears to be trying to update the Hierarchy table and fails. 

So created a new page, with a basic edit form on it. There the default set-up for the *family dropdown* widget is 
`Options: @datasources.TaxonomyFamily.items
Value:@datasource.item.TaxonomyFamily . ` . **NB**: minus the projection because it will not allow it to be selected. It does update the product. Although cannot pick-up the ID using this version. See screen grab.

Comment: Do you need the Id? From what I recall the id was only used to update one of your other dropdown options? So you can technically still accomplish this by still running your query against the other datasource that one of your other option groups is based on and at the same time setting your TaxonomyFamily relation. Just pass your other query parameter in the onValueEdit event of the TaxonomyFamily dropdown.

Comment: So leave the options and value settings but in the onValueEdit run your query against TaxonomyChildren by passing in newValue.id to the query.

Comment: Great Markus, that worked. On the drop-down _ValueEdit_ event I call the function `loadTaxonomyChildById(newValue.Id);` passing it the Id of the selected TaxonomyFamily, changing the features displayed. Now all I need do is have the radio-button widget default to the feature-values of the product being edited. At present, it only correctly displays the value of the 1st feature and marks the others as _no selection_; Radio widget binding = value `@datasources.ProductById.relations.Features.item.Id`. However, this is a different issue,  so thank you for resolving the question raised.

Comment: @WendyHarrison Please post this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Markus wrote:
>   So leave the options and value settings but in the onValueEdit run your query against TaxonomyChildren by passing in **newValue.id** to the query

Great Markus, that worked. On the drop-down ValueEdit event I call the function loadTaxonomyChildById(newValue.Id); passing it the Id of the selected TaxonomyFamily, changing the features displayed.